# Rails rspec tests with neo4j-database gives ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified-error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, neo4j, capybara

I've been trying to get initial Capybara-tests working with my current project that uses graph database (neo4j) as the database. I tried to initialize the tests following the steps mentioned here https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/How-To-Test . My neo4j test server is running in port :7475 When I run

```
rspec spec/features/users_sign_up.rb
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'test' database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:224:in `resolve_connection'
... more stack
spec/features/users_sign_up.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

So it's trying to use the database mentioned in database.yml. What other configuration do I need to set or disable besides adding the

```
 config.neo4j.session_type = :server_db
 config.neo4j.session_path = 'http://localhost:7475'
```

in test.rb?

I've attached the config/test-files to a pastebin-document http://pastebin.com/qXwyrK9k

Comment: Did you use -O to skip installation of ActiveRecord when running `rails new myapp`?

Comment: I didn't actually create the project initially, so I think that the answer to that question is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you're not using ActiveRecord, your app is still loading it and RSpec is angry that it doesn't know where to find its database. There are at least two possible solutions.

Quick and dirty, insert the following into `config/database.yml`:

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

Ensure you have `gem 'sqlite3'` in your Gemfile.

Alternatively, if you know you're not going to use ActiveRecord and don't even want to load it in your app, you can change `application.rb` so it looks like this:

```
# require 'rails/all'
require "active_model/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require 'neo4j/railtie'
```

And then comment out the following lines in your `rails_helper.rb` file:

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the quick and dirty solution worked nicely. I guess the long term solution would be better though, but this works for now at least.